# React Native: What exactly makes JS frames to drop more than UI frames during rapid scroll of FlatList?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In a Bachelor Thesis ( https://www.theseus.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/146232/thesis.pdf?sequence=1 ) a benchmark is made for React Native while scrolling through FlatList with 1000 items each consisting of an image and a text. There are two points present - UI fps and JS fps. I found the explanation for JS framerate ( https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance ), but I still do not clearly understand how scrolling effects the dropped JS frames more than UI frames.

In the thesis the author says "The bigger issue lays at how FlatList in React Native optimize the memory usage. In order to economize memory space, for a dense list with many items, Flat list only renders certain item at once. For certain scenario, such as over speed scrolling, blank blocks will be rendered as placeholders and the fps in JavaScript thread drops significantly. Through those pikes from the graph indicates handling user input and rendering animation together is re- source-demanding." But this does not really explain why the JS frames are dropped, it just states that.

I assume that dropped JS frames come from the fact that through rapid scroll the calls to render and "unrender" are made way to often which creates overhead. But due to my understanding, more drops should be on UI thread rather than JS thread.

Here is the image from the thesis:
[image]

Here is how one item in the FlatList looks like:
[image]

**So the question is:** based on the presented data from the thesis what could causes the JS frames to drop more than UI frames, assuming there are no another background-tasks running which could block the JS thread?

Comment: pdf not loading for me - do you have another link?

Comment: @Abe unfortunately I do not have another link. However, all data relevant to the question is presented in my post.